# What to write in email when sending CV to family friends?

Tags: resume

My dad suggested I send my CV to his friend who works at X Company. The thing is I'm not sure what to write without sounding too desperate.

Comment: Write about why you are sending them the CV and what you hope as the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to look for are samples of a **cover letter with a referral**.

Generally, your email should state:

- Who you are
- What you do
- Who referred you

  - Your relationship to them
  - Their relationship to the company and/or the person you're writing to
- What you'd like to do at the company

  - If there's a specific position open, name it and the reference number if you have it
  - If there's no specific position open, the type of work you're looking for
- That your CV/resume is attached
- Contact information

An example opening:

*Dear Ms. Lee,*

*My name is Lindsey Greene, I am a recent graduate of the University of Texas seeking entry level positions in art design. I was referred to you by my father, Vincent Cobb, a Product Manager at your company.*

You would then follow with normal cover letter content. Cover letters are all about how you'd be a good fit with the company and the role. Talk about how you'd be an asset to them and you won't have to worry about sounding desperate.

Answer (score 0):

> "Hi I'm X I was told to send you my resume by Y, do you have any openings for a Z?"

**What you say in the email is irrelevant**, as long as you don't act like an idiot.

**You are using your connections to get this job**, and while tact is important a decent resume and your dad's reputation is what you are counting on to get you into an interview.

Comment: I think It's rather unfair to downvote someone for describing the nature of nepotism.  I'm describing the world as it is not as it should be.

Comment: Despite what the boo birds say, you've got it right.   The content of the email is not as important as the resume itself.  Drop Dad's name, give a short introduction of who you are, why you're emailing, express a desire to get a job, end it.

Comment: The down votes are more likely genuine disagreement that what's in the email is irrelevant rather than just disliking nepotism. Possibly the down votes are about specific issues with your suggested text.